# Copy one OpenCV OutputArrayOfArrays object to another

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to copy  one OutputArrayOfArrays object to another. Something like this:

```cpp
void function(OutputArrayOfArrays contour) {
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    OutputArrayOfArrays _contour(contours);

    ....Doing something....

    contour = _contour;
}
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
no viable overloaded '='
    contour = _contour;
```

Comment: Since the parameter of your function is called `contour`, do you expect any other input than a `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>`? If not, use this type for your parameter. I think, using the [`_OutputArray`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d2/d9e/classcv_1_1__OutputArray.html) class directly is not recommended.

Comment: @HansHirse Yes parameter will vary other than `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do it for varying types. You will have to handle types specifically. Take a look at functions that use this type in the `opencv` sources and you will see they are handled in specific ways: for example, `findContours` and `split` functions.

For your specific case of `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>`, you can follow the `findContours` way of doing it. Below I have written a simple function to demonstrate this.

```
void testfunction(OutputArrayOfArrays contour) {
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;

    // fill some data
    std::vector<cv::Point> v1;
    v1.push_back(cv::Point(10, 1));
    v1.push_back(cv::Point(11, 2));
    v1.push_back(cv::Point(12, 3));

    std::vector<cv::Point> v2;
    v2.push_back(cv::Point(20, 10));
    v2.push_back(cv::Point(21, 20));

    contours.push_back(v1);
    contours.push_back(v2);

    // output
    contour.create(contours.size(), 1, 0, -1, true);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        std::vector<cv::Point>& v = contours[i];
        contour.create(v.size(), 1, CV_32SC2, i, true);
        Mat m = contour.getMat(i);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < v.size(); j++) {
            m.at<int>(2*j) = v[j].x;
            m.at<int>(2*j+1) = v[j].y;
        }
        std::cout << m << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And the output looks like

```
[10, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3]
[20, 10, 21, 20]
2
3
[10, 1]
[11, 2]
[12, 3]
2
[20, 10]
[21, 20]
```

using the code

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;

testfunction(contours);

std::cout << contours.size() << std::endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    std::vector<cv::Point>& cont = contours[i];
    std::cout << cont.size() << std::endl;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < cont.size(); j++) {
        std::cout << cont[j] << std::endl;
    }
}
```